# c# externalinterface flash

Tags: c#, flash

Does anyone know a way of interact with a flash swf with externalinterface without drawing it?
The flash I want to play only does comunication with an external app and does not show anything.

Is there any way of doing this without Windows.Forms??

Thanks
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this might be to start your swf in projector mode and additionally using other software to start it as a service or just to make it invisible. This assumes your communication works but you don't want to see the window itself.

https://superuser.com/questions/262163/how-to-run-a-program-invisibly